# .NET core deployment to Linux CentOS 7 error: Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x8007000E

Tags: .net, linux, asp.net-core, centos7

I am trying to deploy my .net core 3.1 app to Linux server X64, when I test the deployed app on my pc it is working fine, but when I deploy it to the server it gives this error,
you can see the error and the net info below,
I tried the following solutions:
I upgraded the app to versions 5 and 6,
I created a simple hello world app .net core 5 and deploy it,
I installed another version of .net SDK and runtime
please can someone help with this, do you think the problem is from .net or Linux?
and what could be an option that I haven't tried?
[error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiHkP.png)
[dotnet info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qJfp.png)

Comment: From what I found it comes with message "out of memory". Can you increase RAM on your machine? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/85cd1e40-54f5-41f8-be07-c50e5f42df33/hresult-0x8007000e-eoutofmemory-while-installing-image?forum=quebecservicingdeployment

Comment: Also you have a different error code in your screenshot than in you title. Why is that?

Comment: The error message also means the ERROR_OUTOFMEMORY  "Not enough memory resources are available to complete this operation.". I suggest you could check if your server contains the enough memory. Besides, you said your application is 3.1, I suggest you could try to install the 3.1 runtime to test again instead of using the 5 or 6.

Comment: Yes, I posted the wrong error code, I edited it thank you @Artur